# Why Durva grass is dear to Lord Ganesha

Tags: rituals, ganesha, puja

Why is Durva grass offered to Lord Ganesha ? What is the significance of praying Ganesha with durva grass ?Can any other flower or leaves  used as a substitute for this.

[image]

Comment: you can offer arali flower and erukkam flower which Lord Ganapathy likes very much.   If erukkam plant is continuously worshipped for 12 years with small puja it will turn into Lord vinayaga. This you can see at Datta peedam in Mysore.

Comment: When we do Ganapathi Homam, we offer red arali to vinayaga idol and on the homa kunda also.

Comment: Use already available [tag:ganesha] instead of creating similar tags like [tag:ganesh]. If you've suggestion to rename the existing tag (to your name!) , then you can post on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

> **यो दूर्वाङ्कुरैर्यजति स वैश्रवणोपमो भवति ।**
>   **यो लाजैर्यजति स यशोवान् भवति । स मेधावान् भवति ।**
>   **यो मोदकसहस्रेण यजति स वाञ्छितफलमवाप्नोति ।**
>   **यस्साज्यसमिद्भिर्यजति स सर्वं लभते स सर्वं लभते ॥१६॥**
>
> 16.1: He who worships (Ganapati) with tender Durva Grass will become Prosperous like Kubera,
>   16.2: He who worships (Ganapati) with Parched Rice will become Glorious (i.e. will have Name and Fame),
>   16.3: He will (also) become Medhavan (filled with Medha or retentive capacity of the mind),
>   16.4: He who worships (Ganapati) with thousand Modakas (a type of Sweetmeat), he willobtain his Desired Fruits,
>   16.5: He who worships (Ganapati) with Twigs dipped in Ghee, he obtains Everything, he obtains Everything,
>
> **Ganapati Atharvashirsha (Ganapati Upanishad)**

**The legend Of Analasura and  Shree Ganesh -:**

**The Story Of Durva** -: Once a demon named Analasura caused trouble in the heavens. He emitted fire from his eyes and destroyed whatever came in his way. The Gods frightened and asked Lord Ganesha’s help . Shree Ganesha assured them that He will finish off the demon and restore peace. In the faught with , Analasura  attacking Lord Ganesha with fire Him. At that time Lord Ganesha, took the giant form and swallowed  the demon . After this , Lord Ganesha felt extremely uneasy due to the heat inside His body. So, the moon came to His help and stood on Ganesha’s head. Thus, He was named ‘Bhaalachandra’ (भालचंद्र). Lord Vishnu gave His lotus to bring down the heat, Lord Shiva tied His cobra around Ganesha’s belly. But nothing could cure the heat. Finally, a few sages came with 21 durvas and placed it on Ganesha’s head. Miraculously, the heat went off.  **And thus Durva grass became dear to Shree Ganesha .So Lord Ganesha declared that whoever worships Him with durva grass will forever receive His blessings.**

Sri Ganesh is easily pleased. Just by offering Him a little durva grass. (21 blades). 
According to Ayurveda Durva grass also has some medicinal properties.

Comment: Can you cite the source of this story.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar  You can add the source from Ganesha Purana Upasana Khanda given [on page 309](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=WcKf113gPwwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=durva+ganesha+purana&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG-4iL0fDWAhULq48KHcFGC_sQ6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q&f=false). Fortunately it's in English.